# koa loosing context (this)

Tags: generator, ecmascript-6, koa

I am exploring koajs and thought I have understood generators, but obviously that is not the case.

```js
module.exports.request = function* request() {
  'use strict';
  try {
    yield check;
    yield send;
  } catch (ValidationError) {
    this.status = 400;
    this.body = ValidationError.message;
  }
};

function* check() {
  expect(this.body.param).to.be.a('number');
}

function* send() {
  this.body.token = '654afssd98sf';
}
```

This results in the error `Cannot read property 'status' of undefined`, so somehow the context is lost.

The below snippet works, but is not the desired behavior, as is sends out the response even if the check throws an error.

```js
module.exports.request = function *request(){
  'use strict';
  try{
    yield checkTransaction;
  } catch(ValidationError){
    this.status = 400;
    this.body = ValidationError.message;
  }
  yield sendTransaction;
};
```

If you have advice on how to architecture a koa application, I am glad as well because there are a lot of examples, but none is really covering a best practice for koa architectural design.

Edit: Context:

```
var koa = require('koa');

var requestLogger = require('koa-logger');
var body = require('koa-body');
var route = require('koa-route');

var app = module.exports = koa();

var test = require('./controllers/test');

// Logger
if(app.env === 'development'){
  app.use(requestLogger());
}
app.use(body());

app.use(function *setup(next){
  this.type = 'application/json';
  yield next;
});

app.use(route.post('/test', test.request));
app.use(route.put('/test', test.authenticate))

if (!module.parent) {
  app.listen(3000);
  console.log('listening on port 3000');
}
```

Comment: I need a bit more context to understand what you are trying to do.  Can you add the code where you use the request generator (module.exports.request)?

Comment: I am still very interested in an answer, if you can spare the time.

Comment: did you try to add next to function*request(next) ?

Answer (score 0):

After commenting and thinking about, I am sure your mistake had bin forgetting to add the next to the generator function.

```js
module.exports.request = function* request(next) {
  'use strict';
  try {
    yield check;
    yield send;
  } catch (ValidationError) {
    this.status = 400;
    this.body = ValidationError.message;
  }
};

function* check() {
  expect(this.body.param).to.be.a('number');
}

function* send() {
  this.body.token = '654afssd98sf';
}
```

Compare [Koa Error Handling guide](https://github.com/koajs/koa/wiki/Error-Handling)